# Open push notification tray on iOS hardware device using Appium

Tags: python, ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium

Is there any way to open push notification tray for iOS on hardware device using Appium and Python.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, there no way to open push notification tray for iOS on hardware device using Appium and Python, or any iOS public API.

Comment: How can we test push notification on iOS using Appium? Please suggest.